# wordpress advanced custom fields google map api key

Tags: wordpress, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, advanced-custom-fields, api-key

I have a problem with loading google map with the Advanced Custom Field plugin. I make everything like in the instruction on the plugin page here https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/google-map. 
I add google-map field in ACF, but on the page where it should be it appears for a second, and then disappears with the     inscription "Oops! Something went wrong. This page didn't load Google Maps correctly. See the JavaScript console for technical details." (see the screenshot). Console says that I need to set the Google API key. I guess I also need to modify some strings in .js file from the ACF instruction, but I don't know which ones. May be someone could help.
Thank you in advance.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mva8s.png)

Comment: I have found temporary solution here https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/google-maps-field-needs-setting-to-add-api-key/

Answer (score 22, accepted):

ACF updated the [Google Map documentation](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/google-map/)

You first have to [get a Maps API key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key) and make sure you activate the following APIs :

- Maps JavaScript API
- Geocoding API
- Places API

Then register the API key in your `functions.php`

### If using ACF free

```
function my_acf_google_map_api( $api ){
    $api['key'] = 'xxx';
    return $api;
}
add_filter('acf/fields/google_map/api', 'my_acf_google_map_api');
```

### If using ACF pro

```
function my_acf_init() {
    acf_update_setting('google_api_key', 'xxx');
}

add_action('acf/init', 'my_acf_init');
```

In my case I had to delete & recreate the field so that it saves correctly.

Comment: This wo.rked for me! Thanks

Comment: The ACF site says only "Maps JavaScript API, Geocoding API and Places API" must be activated. Tested and works.

Comment: Thanks @HenningFischer, just updated the answer based on your comment :)

Answer (score 1):

A solution could be editing the functions.php in your template

```
//TODO: fix api key for advanced custom field
add_action('acf/fields/google_map/api', function($api){
$api['key'] = '<YOUR_API_KEY>';
return $api;
});
```

[or you can check my article for a complete solution](http://ericphamhoang.com/wordpress-advanced-custom-field-google-missing-key-map-error-quick-fix/)

Answer (score 1):

add this line in your script..replace with your key..

```
<script src="javascripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR-API-KEY"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/jquery.googlemap.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a couple of different solutions for this issue, but before starting to explain what to do let me remember to you to get a google maps api key.
I followed [these instructions](http://listify.astoundify.com/article/856-create-a-google-maps-api-key) because I'm using Listify theme, but I'm pretty sure they can help you regardless the theme you have.

Here my solutions:

#### frontend

Somewhere (I guess in your `functions.php` or in `your-awesome-widget.php`) you should have a line like these

`wp_enqueue_script( 'googlemaps_api' );`

or

`wp_enqueue_script( 'googlemaps' );`

the solution I've found is add the key in the script registration before enqueuing it, in this way

```
wp_register_script('googlemaps', 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key='.$YOUR_API_KEY, false, '3');

wp_enqueue_script('googlemaps');
```

#### Backend

This one is quick and totally dirty because I've read that ACF support is already working on the official solution, so, for me, is not a problem if **it will be erased by a plugin update**.

Open those two files:

- advanced-custom-fields/js/input.min.js
- advanced-custom-fields/js/input.js (in theory if you are using the .min version this one is useless)

This piece of code is repeated twice in each file:

`google.load('maps', '3', { other_params: $.param(self.api), callback: function(){` ...

change those two occurencies adding the key as querystring, in this way

`other_params: $.param(i.api) + 'key=YOUR_API_KEY', callback` ...

Et voilá! It should work.

The official page about the topic is [here](https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/google-maps-field-needs-setting-to-add-api-key/)

I hope to have been helpful!

Comment: Further to this one, make sure you've also enabled _all_ of the required Google APIs for the API key you are using. I was having this problem and I worked out it was because the Maps API by itself doesn't have all the functionality you need for the ACF Google map element to work as intended. I had to add the Place API as well.

Answer (score 0):

With the current version (4.4) of ACF, you can find functions.php in the template you are using and add this to the end of the code:

```
function my_acf_google_map_api( $api ){
    $api['key'] = 'YOUR_API_KEY';
    return $api;
}
add_filter('acf/fields/google_map/api', 'my_acf_google_map_api');
```

Change 'YOUR_API_KEY' to your API KEY generated from Google.

Comment: This answer isn't very low quality but this is a very similar than an existing answer. There is nothing new in this answer.